# Loop through array of images with Javascript shows image placeholder as the previous/next image when at first/last index of array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, image, carousel

[image]

```
//array of images
const programmingLanguages = [jsIcon, htmlIcon, cssIcon, csharpIcon];
```

> Functions for showing next and previous images.

```
   function incrementLanguage() {
   if (languageIndex + 1 === programmingLanguages.length) {
     setlanguageIndex(0);
     } else {
   setlanguageIndex(languageIndex + 1);
    }

    }
  function decrementLanguage() {
      if (languageIndex === 0) {
   setlanguageIndex(programmingLanguages.length - 1);
    } else {
   setlanguageIndex(languageIndex - 1);
    }
```

> here i render my images the issue is when i start the program on programmingLanguages [0] it shows the img placeholder to the left because it goes outside the array. Is it possible to add an if statement to check if the value goes below 0 then it should start from the last index?

```
        /*<img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[if(languageIndex -1 < 0 set 
          langugeIndex to programmingLanguage.length? )]} alt=""> 
        </img>*/

        // this is the previous image                           
        <img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex - 1]} alt=""> 
        </img> 
                 
        //this is the current image displayed     
        <img id="languageIcon" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex]} alt=""></img>

        //this is the next image
        <img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex + 1]} alt=""> 
         </img>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[(languageIndex - 1 + programmingLanguages.length) % programmingLanguages.length]} alt="" />
         
//this is the current image displayed     
<img id="languageIcon" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex]} alt="" />

//this is the next image
<img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[(languageIndex + 1) % programmingLanguages.length]} alt="" />
```

or

```
<img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex === 0 ? programmingLanguages.length - 1 : languageIndex - 1]} alt="" />
         
//this is the current image displayed     
<img id="languageIcon" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex]} alt="" />

//this is the next image
<img id="languageIconSmall" src={programmingLanguages[languageIndex === programmingLanguages.length -1 ? 0 : languageIndex  + 1) % programmingLanguages.length]} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the three `src` values outside JSX like:

```js
// prev or last of the array
const prevSrc = programmingLanguages[languageIndex - 1] || programmingLanguages[programmingLanguages.length - 1];
// current
const currentSrc = programmingLanguages[languageIndex];
// next or first of the array
const nextSrc = programmingLanguages[languageIndex + 1] || programmingLanguages[0];
```

Then just refer to them as:

```
<img class="languageIconSmall" src={prevSrc} alt=""/>
<img class="languageIcon" src={currentSrc} alt=""/>
<img class="languageIconSmall" src={nextSrc} alt=""/>
```

Remember not to use duplicated `id`s - classes are just fine.